# Background color of cells in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, color, context

I'd like to set the background colors for cells to indicate their relations. How can I do this in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on which table macros you are using (`\starttabe`, `\starttabulate` or `\bTABE`/`\startTABLE`).  I will assume `\bTABLE`, because that is the most versatile option.

Each cell of a TABLE is a `\frame`, so it takes all the options of a `\frame`. You can color the background of a frame using

```
\frame[background=color, backgroundcolor=red]{...}
```

The same syntax works for TABLEs. You can either pass the color the a specific cell manually,

```
\bTABLE[background=color]
 \bTR 
    \bTD one   \eTD 
    \bTD two   \eTD
    \bTD three \eTD
 \eTR
 \bTR 
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=red] one   \eTD 
    \bTD two   \eTD
    \bTD three \eTD
 \eTR
\eTABLE
```

or use setups to select the cell

```
\setupTABLE[1][2][background=color,backgroundcolor=red]
% col 1 row 2

\bTABLE
 \bTR 
    \bTD one   \eTD 
    \bTD two   \eTD
    \bTD three \eTD
 \eTR
 \bTR 
    \bTD one   \eTD 
    \bTD two   \eTD
    \bTD three \eTD
 \eTR
\eTABLE
```

Comment: Both displays as black-and-white tables.

Comment: If you are using mkii, you need to add `\setupcolors[state=start]` to get colors.